# How do I get Gradle for Android to find a library's test code from within other test code?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, android-testing

I have an Android application with two library layers underneath it. Each library has its own test code. I would like the upper library’s test code to extend the lower library’s test code, but I can’t figure out how to get Gradle to find the lower library’s test code (it only finds the production code).

My file structure looks like this:

```
myproject/
 + myapp/
   + src/
     + main/
       + java
         + com/myapp
 + lib1/
   + src/
     + main/
       + java
         + com/myapp/lib1
     + androidTest
       + java
         + com/myapp/lib1/test
 + lib2/
   + src/
     + main/
       + java
         + com/myapp/lib2
     + androidTest
       + java
         + com/myapp/lib2/test
```

The gradle file for the app looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android { ... }
dependencies {
  compile project(':lib2')
}
```

The gradle file for lib2 looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android { ... }
dependencies {
  compile project(':lib1')
}
```

The gradle file for lib1 looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android { ... }
```

When I run “gradle connectedCheck” I get this:

```
...
:lib2:generateDebugTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:lib2:compileDebugTestJava
myproject/lib2/src/androidTest/java/com/myapp/lib2/test/SubClass.java:10: error: package com.myapp.lib1.test does not exist
import com.myapp.lib1.test.BaseClass;
```

I have tried adding various androidTestCompile lines to the dependencies section of lib2’s gradle file, but none of them help.

Anybody know how to make this work?

EDIT:
Sorry, I didn't mention that I also have a settings.gradle in the myproject folder that looks like this:

```
include ':lib1'
include ':lib2'
include ':myapp'
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your gradle does not know connections of myapp, lib1 and lib2 modules.

Try to add some settings.gradle in modules that are using another one. For your structure i recommend to make additional gradle files in root:

for example in myproject/

settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'myproject'
include 'myapp'
include 'lib1'
include 'lib2'
```

and then write gradle.build for all module where you clarify type of all project for example ear etc.

You can also connect modules separately.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question to add my settings.gradle, which does have includes for the modules, although I'm not specifying the project name. Is that important? Also, I don't understand what you mean about clarifying the type of project, and how I would connect the modules. Currently the only connections are the references to library modules in the compile statements.

Comment: clarifying the type of project <- sry guy i forgot that you are talking about android project, a said that in context of java, or java EE application (for example type is EAR, WAR etc, but it does not applies your Q-tion). try to add in every module gradle setting, and there set dependency - for example - on include 'lib2' in my app